# Hyperledger Console usability

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm tasked with creating a hyperledger application that will represent a consortium of same-skilled organizations.
I have the barebones prototype with a network of 2 orgs, built by following the fabric-samples example that I created as a capstone project; I am looking to upgrade the application to a production level.

My question is, is there a GUI/platform available to create and maintain hyperledger fabric networks?

What are the alternatives for tools like the Console?
What would be the best way to start building such an application considering the goal is to get to the production level?

Is IBM Cloud Blockchain Platform the best option for me?

Thank you for taking the time to reply.

I know of Hyperledger Console. I have used it previously for school projects. But can it be used to create and maintain+govern a production-grade HLF app?

Answer (score 0):

IBM Blockchain Platform on IBM Cloud is withdrawn (https://www.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?htmlfid=872/ENUSWP22-0062&infotype=AN&subtype=CA). But the console is open sourced as https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/fabric-operations-console